# Git clone a branch, not master

Tags: git, branch, bitbucket, git-bash, git-clone

I use Git Bash for bitbucket. I have created a branch and I pushed some commits, other people pushed commits in master.
Now I am on a different machine. I want to clone or download the solution of the latest commit of my branch and not the master? How can I do that?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `--branch` option to `git clone`, which allows you to specify which branch is initially checked out in the cloned repository.

```
git clone --branch mybranch $URL/foo
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
git clone $URL/foo
cd foo
git checkout mybranch
cd ..
```

Answer (score 14):

if you use git you can do that easily with `git clone -b <name_of_branch> <URL_Repository>`, if you want to pull do `git pull origin <name_of_branch> <URL_Repository>` .

Regards

Comment: yes but I have no solution at all, where and how should I mention the repository URL?

Comment: I edited my question, the URL goes after the branch name, about you merge conflicts, probably you already have a working copy with changes of other user and need to stash  your changes in order to get the latest changes in the branch repository you can do this with  `git stash` in the folder of your working copy

Answer (score 9):

You can use below solution:-

Step1: Clone the repo by using below command following by credentials.

```
git clone <Repository URL>
```

Step 2: checkout the branch and pull the latest code from there.

```
git checkout -b <your origin branch>
```

Step 3: pull the latest code

```
git pull origin <your origin branch name where latest code is available>
```

Comment: I get merge conflicts at the step 3

Comment: what am i supposed to do

Comment: @mister_giga I am stuck here too. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: it says fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: Make sure you running the above commands in folder which contains ".git"